# How to implement a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter when working with two_line_list_item?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In my Activity, inside **onCreate()** I have this:

```
final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String,MessageViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, MessageViewHolder>(
                String.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                databaseReferenceCurrentUser
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, String model, int position) {
                viewHolder.mText.setText(model);



                   }
                };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mText;
        public MessageViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            mText = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }
```

Now, I wish to populate my RecyclerView with objects of type Parishioner, I have defined the class :

```
public class Parishioner {

    private String parishionerName;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Parishioner(String parishionerName, String phoneNumber) {
        this.parishionerName = parishionerName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Parishioner (){
    }

    public String getParishionerName() {
        return parishionerName;
    }

    public void setParishionerName(String parishionerName) {
        this.parishionerName = parishionerName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

When adding a new Parishioner in my `DB`, I use

```
databaseReferenceCurrentUser.push().setValue(new Parishioner(editTextPName.getText().toString(),editTextPPhone.getText().toString()));
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change model class String to Parishioner.

```
final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Parishioner, MessageViewHolder> adapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Parishioner, MessageViewHolder>(
                Parishioner.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                databaseReferenceCurrentUser) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Parishioner model, int position) {
                   viewHolder.mName.setText(model.getParishionerName());
                   viewHolder.mPhone.setText(model.getPhoneNumber());
               }
            };

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mName;
    TextView mPhone;

    public MessageViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        mName= (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        mPhone= (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to have both the name and the phone number of each of the parishioners displayed in  the RecyclerView

Comment: @SimpleFuzz then you should update you holder class, i will update my answer.

Comment: Before posting the question, I had already tried this, but when the activity is launched I get the following exception: "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type packagename.Parishioner" this is inside my main Fragment inside a Navigation Drawer Activity , not sure if it's relevant or not ... it shouldn't be. If I choose to display only the names it works fine.

Comment: @SimpleFuzz I think problem is your data structure. Can you share your databaseReferenceCurrentUser node?

Comment: Well if I understood correctly what you meant by that, inside my code databaseReferenceCurrentUser node is constructed as follows: "DATABASENAME.firebaseio.com/Users/" +  uniqueIDforUser  +"/parishioners"

Comment: To be specific, String localUserEmailUniqueID = getEmailAddressUniqueID(localUserEmail);
String dbUsersRoot = "https://DATABASENAME.firebaseio.com/Users/";
String dbUniqueRefForCurrentUser = dbUsersRoot + localUserEmailUniqueID +"/parishioners";

DatabaseReference databaseReferenceCurrentUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(dbUniqueRefForCurrentUser);

Comment: @SimpleFuzz no, i want to know your data in parishioners node. Because i suspect parishioners node consist of string list and it shouldn't be.

Comment: [danym1296] : { "parishioners" : { "-KX5Us61HwlWyEaJBvHA" : { parishionerName: "Donald Smith" phoneNumber: "0744459895" } "-KX5Ut752a-hdpfPscts" :  parishionerName: "Michelle Wolfe" phoneNumber: "0432654392" } } [robert47] : { "parishioners" : { "-KX1G_Q130sWitNGzlAR" : { parishionerName: "Penelope Cruz" phoneNumber: "0271772388" } "-KX1GpvdE5i9UR2ZaX0K" : "x2", parishionerName: "Michelle Wolfe" phoneNumber: "00264187552" } }

Comment: I added a comment with it, then accidentally removed it and added again ...

Comment: @SimpleFuzz Everything seems normal. Your parishioner node structure is true. 'Can't convert String to Parishioner' should not be occur. Check your databaseReferenceCurrentUser variable, maybe it refer wrong node. Use dataSnapshot.getValue() in databaseReferenceCurrentUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent

Comment: If I change my adapter to support a string instead of Parishioner and inside populateViewHolder() method I call setText(someString) the recyclerview gets populated as it should . And it uses the databaseReferenceCurrentUser ; however for this to work I had to structure the database to be like this [danym1296] : {
      "parishioners" : {
        "-KX5Us61HwlWyEaJBvHA" : "Donald Smith"
  "-KX5Ut752a-hdpfPscts" : "Penelope Cruz2",
        "-KX1GpvdE5i9UR2ZaX0K" : "Michelle Wolfe"
  }
}